# WordPress - Broken Portfolio Links

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I'm currently trying to figure out why our portfolio links are broken (404 Error).

They work just fine on our testing server and when you visit the site from a mobile device.

Example link: https://www.deepsea.com/portfolio-items/abyss-servicos-tecnicos/

I've already tried resetting the permalinks but this did not work. It appears to be a common problem and this was the most recommended solution, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Has anybody run into anything like this?

Comment: Just saying the links are broken is not enough information to help. How would you like them to be?

Comment: What do you mean? I just need them to work and direct the user exactly when the link states.